# Hide Questions Asked?

Tags: support, questions

Is it possible to hide questions asked in the user profile?

I have some questions that I posted recently that I wouldn't like potential employer's to find as they could impact one's ability to be hired.

Comment: If you don't want it seen, don't put it on the Interwebs. You can always delete the questions, though, if you're afraid of any negative impact they may have.

Comment: @Joel, *actually* unfortunately you can't delete the question, if it has answers. (A moderator can, but they might not be inclined to for this reason.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only way to prevent anyone to use what you wrote against you, is to anonymize your profile (a simple request to team@stackexchange.com is enough) OR create an anonymous profile to ask questions.

I personaly think that asking question (even stupid question) is just a proof you are able to consume your employer's money wisely instead of staying in the exact same level of knowledge for years or worse, trying to solve a bug for weeks that someone on the internet can solve in 5 minutes.

Comment: +1 for adding "stupid" questions as proof that the attempt of improvement is highly preferable to probable stagnation.

Comment: Very useful answer, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way to do that.

The best I can advise is to either phrase your questions in such a way that they obscure your specific situation and make it harder to trace it to you, or avoid posting things you would regret saying on the internet.

You can also create a new account on the site that's not using your real name or picture, or post from an unregistered account.